# listview custom adapter duplicate items

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Why is this returning some duplicate items?

And when I set `convertView` to null at start it works, but I lose the smooth scrolling

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHoilder viewhoilder = null;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_unit, null, true);
        viewhoilder = new ViewHoilder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewhoilder);
    }else{
        viewhoilder = (ViewHoilder) convertView.getTag();
    }



    final Post_Unit post_unit = getItem(position);
    if (post_unit.getPost_unit_type() == 10) {



        Load_text(post_unit,viewhoilder);

        Load_images(post_unit, viewhoilder);

        Load_videos(post_unit, viewhoilder);




    return convertView;
}
```

here my ViewHolder

```
 public class  ViewHoilder{
    TextView post_username,post_date,post_content,video_title;
    LinearLayout video_layout;
    FrameLayout post_unit_btn_add_like;
    ImageView video_thumbnail,img_post_unit_content_midea_img_imageview;
    ScrollView post_unit_content_midea_imgs;
    LinearLayout post_unit_content_midea_imgs_layout;
    public ViewHoilder(View v) {
        this.post_username = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_unit_username);
        this.post_date = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_unit_date);
        this.post_content = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_unit_content_text);
        this.video_layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.post_unit_content_midea_video);
        this.video_title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.post_unit_video_title);
        this.video_thumbnail = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.post_unit_video_logo);
        this.img_post_unit_content_midea_img_imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.post_unit_content_midea_img_imageview);
        this.post_unit_btn_add_like = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.post_unit_content_midea_img);
        this.post_unit_content_midea_imgs = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.post_unit_content_midea_imgs);
        this.post_unit_content_midea_imgs_layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.post_unit_content_midea_imgs_layout);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code
from

```
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_unit, null, true);
```

to

```
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_unit, parent, false);
```

Comment: check your arraylist then

Answer (score 0):

add **onDetachedFromWindow()** @Override method in your adapter and   add holder.setIsRecyclable(false); 
sample:

> @Override onDetachedFromWindow(){
>    holder.setIsRecyclable(false); 
>    }

**Note**: listView is deprecated so use recyclerview view
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: there is no such @method in ArrayAdapter ??

Comment: refer this doc: [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Answer (score 0):

as per, Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)

Please update your line,

convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_unit, null, true);

as

convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_unit, null, false);

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Will the problem is a logical problem in loading a image and videos and in the get view why of work ,,, in the image load it check for if image is empty or not so when it return a view for recycling it return an view with the recycled stuff and when it check for the image if it empty it fails since it get an recycled view so it insert an image in the item with no images.

the solution is to reset all images and stuff that have a check condition to set it so when the check fail you don't get the recycled stuff

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (null == convertView) {
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) LinearLayout.inflate(this.context, 
        R.layout.message, null);
    Log.d("SeenDroid", String.format("Get view %d", position));
    TextView title = new TextView(view.getContext());
    title.setText(this.items.get(position).getTitle());
    view.addView(title);
    return view;
} else {
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    TextView title = (TextView) view.getChildAt(0);
    title.setText(this.items.get(position).getTitle());
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: I solved  the issue check my answer above ,, thanks any way